# Best way to flag a row for future deletion?

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I have `users` table where a row *can* be marked for future deletion, so I'm looking for the best way to do this.

I've thought of two options so far:

1. Add a `delete_date` to the `users` table.

   Every night a process will query the table and get all users that match `delete_date` with current date and delete them.
2. Create a `users_to_be_deleted` table with the `id` of the row in `users` table to be deleted along with a `delete_date`.

   Every night a process will query `users` table and join on `users_to_be_deleted` in order to identify which users should be deleted (matching `delete_date` with current date), and then delete them.

Basically, Option 1 adds a column that can (and in most cases will) contain `NULL` marks, while Option 2 has no columns that accept `NULLs` at all, but will require an additional `JOIN`.

Considering that most users will not be marked for deletion (an estimate is that only 10-20% will), which option is the most efficient? What are the pros and cons of each option?

Comment: This is a perfect chance to use a partial / functional index. Create the field "tobedeleted" etc and index on that as "create index on table (id) where tobedeleted is not null"

Comment: When considering the differences, note that the time to update/insert during the day should be weighed appropriately against an off-hours process; generally, time to complete during business hours is much more significant than whatever amount of time is necessary off-hours.

Comment: I assume that there are no `FOREIGN KEY` issues here. If I were you, I'd fire a `TRIGGER` for the `ON DELETE` step - just delete the user record for the active table and move it to a table called deleted_users with a date and time of deletion as well as the deleting programme operative.

Comment: @ScottMarlowe Sounds pretty good, it will make option 1 more appealing. I'll give it a shot. Thank you!

Comment: @RDFozz In this scenario both actions (mark to deletion and deleting the row) will be executed during off-hours; in fact, both actions take place within a batch process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normal guiding principles are to,

1. Not delete data. It's easy to put a boolean flag on the data `deleted` and then for it to seem like the data is deleted to users, without it really being deleted. Do you really want the data gone forever?
2. Not create 1:1 relationships. If it's 1:1 just merge it together.
3. *"Match `delete_date` with current date and delete them"* I would suggest storing the `delete_queue_date` instead. The date that the data entered the queue. That's what matters. The date the row actually gets deleted is a function of that. Generally you don't store `f(x)` on the table, you store `x`.

Comment: So, this principles point to avoid that extra table, that is, option 1. Are there any drawbacks i should be aware of? (BTW, i **do** want the data deleted forever).

Comment: Nope, though you may want to read about table packing with PostgreSQL if you're worried about space. You can also store it in a boolean, and the previous suggestion to use a partial index could be valid too, depending on how often you run the reaper.

Comment: Currently space is not an issue (but, in the future it could be, so ill refer to table packing). How could it be stored as a boolean? I will be great, but a date is needed to identify if the row must be deleted (BTW, at any time the recored could be _removed from deletion_, if it is done before being deleted).

Comment: Oh my bad, that's right you're storing the tz because it has sit in queue for a set amount of time, forgot. Scratch that. Normally, I just store a flag. Different workloads.